# Preserve Exit Code in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I have a simple application written using C# which accepts a operands via command-line parameters and reports success or failure via an exit code. When run on Windows XP via a batch file:

```
MyProg.exe ...//Snip: Command-line Params ...
echo %errorlevel%;
```

The exit code returned is the value set by the application. However, when the same app is invoked on Linux using a bash-script:

```
mono MyProg.exe ...//Snip: Command-line Params ...
echo $?;
```

The exit code reported to the shell is always zero and not the value set by the app. Is there any way to capture the exit code set by the application *before* it is modified by mono?

I've tried using `Environment.Exit()` and `Application.Exit()`, there seems to be no difference with respect to this issue. Also, the application is explicitly setting `Environment.ExitCode` before calling the exit functions.

Here is a simple WinForms app which reproduces this behaviour:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
 public class Form1 : Form
 {
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;

  public Form1()
  {
     #region Create UI Stuff
     this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
     this.SuspendLayout();
     // 
     // button1
     // 
     this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, 22);
     this.button1.Name = "button1";
     this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
     this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
     this.button1.Text = "ExitZero";
     this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
     this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
     // 
     // button2
     // 
     this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(114, 70);
     this.button2.Name = "button2";
     this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
     this.button2.TabIndex = 0;
     this.button2.Text = "ExitOne";
     this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
     this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
     // 
     // Form1
     // 
     this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
     this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
     this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(310, 136);
     this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
     this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
     this.Name = "Form1";
     this.Text = "Form1";
     this.ResumeLayout(false);
     #endregion
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Environment.ExitCode = 0;
     //Environment.Exit(0);
     Application.Exit();
  }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Environment.ExitCode = 1;
     //Environment.Exit(1);
     Application.Exit();
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono doesn't rewrite anything. My test app:

```
pakrym@ubuntu:/home/pakrym# cat exit.cs 
class Program
{
 public static void Main()
 {
      System.Environment.Exit(1);
 }
}
pakrym@ubuntu:/home/pakrym# mono ./exit.exe 
pakrym@ubuntu:/home/pakrym# echo $?
1
pakrym@ubuntu:/home/pakrym# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 2.6.7 (Debian 2.6.7-5ubuntu3)
Copyright (C) 2002-2010 Novell, Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
SIGSEGV:       altstack
Notifications: epoll
Architecture:  x86
Disabled:      none
```

Comment: I'm on quite an old version on mono, executing `mono --version` yields: `Mono JIT compiler version 2.0.1 (tarball)`. Also, the script invokes the app as `mono MyProg.exe` rather than `mono ./MyApp.exe`. Need to look further into both of these differences and see if either of them is the cause.

Comment: Its not impossible, but, unless there is no other workaround available, I'd prefer not to upgrade.

Comment: Ok, just tried modifying the script and invoking the app as `mono ./MyApp.exe` and there is nothing different. The exit code still stays `0`.

Comment: Then I think it's old mono bug, as work around you can output exit code to temp file

Comment: Yeah, thats the last resort and I'd rather not go there. First, I'll try upgrading to newer version of Mono on a test/scratch PC and see how it goes. Thanks!