# C# Console Value in Windows Send Linux with Wine

Tags: c#, linux, return, wine

I have C# console program in windows server. I run command in Linux with wine. When wine run in Linux, İt always returns 0 (Linux command "$?" show last program return value). İf program return -5, I see 0 in Linux again. Because console program run. But I want to take it in linux that returns the value. How can I understand this return value? İs it possible?

Comment: What version is your Mono? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9372977/preserve-exit-code-in-mono).

Comment: I dont use Mono. I run with wine. That is:
    wine <path>/<program>.exe
there is native windows dll and its dont run with mono. if it is .net dll, I will do. But I dont. Am i right?

Comment: I think you're right. Sorry, my mistake.

Comment: No problem if ı am right cause I know that